# sqlcl-20.4.2.35 Error Message = no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path , when trying to connect as SYSDBA

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe, sqlcl

i try to connect as SYSDBA to private oracle 11g which running remotely in docker
when i connect with a simple user everything working the problem is only with SYSDBA
but i keep getting :

```
C:\Dev\devops\oracle\sqlcl-20.4.2.35.2359\sqlcl\bin>sql SYS/PASS@10.0.33.555:95084/XE

SQLcl: Release 20.4 Production on Wed Mar 31 17:21:48 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

  USER          = sys
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:oci8:@10.0.33.555:95084/XE
  Error Message = no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path
  USER          = sys
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.33.555:95084/XE
  Error Message = ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

i doanloded the [instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.10.0.0.0dbru][1]

```
echo %ORACLE_HOME%
C:\Dev\devops\oracle\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.10.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_19_10

echo %PATH%
C:\Dev\devops\oracle\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.10.0.0.0dbru\instantclient_19_10;C:\.....
```

i try from windows 10 to linux
[1]: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html